# How to align a set of views(button, image) horizontally center

Tags: android

Here xml code i tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home_icon"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="OnHomeSelected"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivnetconstatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ledred"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

output generated using above xml file

[image]

I want to align home image & home button to center and red circle image to right of the layout.

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: you should use relative layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home_icon"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
        android:onClick="OnHomeSelected"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivnetconstatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ledred"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your layout like this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivnetconstatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/home_icon" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="OnHomeSelected" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnHome"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ledred" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) which provide you mutiple properties to align views.

shot try with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="OnHomeSelected" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivnetconstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```